# Returning html from a JQuery function.

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to dynamically build a series of check boxes by using an web service and parsing the xml...

I am tryng to return it to an already existing modal with this code:
    html += "Hello ";
    html += loadSeviceLineXML();
    html += " World ";
but get this:  Hello [object Object] World

If I have it write to it's own window it writes correctly. Strangely if pop the alert(): at the end of the function, the [object Object] will still show, but after it, all the html will show correctly before the "World":
Hello [object Object]
Advisory
    Business Consulting Service
        Business intelligence ＆ analytics
        Change and program management
        Performance improvement

This is the code for my function:

```
    function loadSeviceLineXML()  //buildParams
    {     

        jQuery.support.cors = true;     
        var URL = "http://sharepoint.com/_layouts/TaxonomyService/TaxonomyWebService.asmx/GetTermsXML?search=Service%20Line";
        var html = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URL,
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {

               // var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400, height=600,  scrollbars=yes");
                //myWindow.document.write("<form action='' method='get'>");

                $(data).find("MainTerm").each(function() {

                     var mainTerm = $(this).attr("Name");
                     var mainTermId = $(this).attr("Id");                       
                    if(mainTerm != undefined){
                        html += "<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + mainTermId + "'>" + mainTerm + "</li>";
                        html +="<ul>";
                        $(data).find("Sector").each(function() {
                                var sector = $(this).attr("Name");
                                var sectorId = $(this).attr("Id");   //$(this).find("Name").text();
                                var sectorParent = $(this).attr("Parent");
                                if(sector != undefined  && sectorParent == mainTerm ){
                                    html +="<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + sectorId + "'>" + sector + "</li>";
                                    html +="<ul>";

                                    $(data).find("SubSector").each(function(){
                                            var subSector = $(this).attr("Name");
                                            var subSectorId = $(this).attr("Id");
                                            var subSectorParent = $(this).attr("Parent");
                                            if(subSector != undefined && subSectorParent == sector ){
                                                html +="<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + subSectorId + "'>" + subSector +"</li>";
                                            }                                                   
                                    });  
                                    html +="</ul>";
                                }                               
                        });
                        html +="</ul>";

                    }

                    //myWindow.document.write("</ul>") 

                });  
                //alert("html " + html);   <--- this displays all the tags.
                // myWindow.document.write("</form>");
             }
        }); 

        return html;        
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous.. you can't return the `html` from your function that way. How are you calling your function?

Comment: I am just using the function name.  loadSeviceLineXML();  I am not very experienced with JQuery.  Is there a better way to parse the XML.  The Ajax call was about the only way I found to be able to cycle through the xml to create the html tags I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sort answer is that you are returning a Ajax callback and not the string you are trying to build inside of it.  The long answer is you need to reorganize your approach.  Instead of trying to make a synchronous function the returns html, why not try a function that has inside of it the code to set it's own output (when the asynchronous call is completed).  To modify your function in this way you might try:

```
function loadSeviceLineXML() //buildParams
  {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var URL = "http://sharepoint.com/_layouts/TaxonomyService/TaxonomyWebService.asmx/GetTermsXML?search=Service%20Line";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: URL,
      dataType: "xml",
      contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
        var html = "";
        $(data).find("MainTerm").each(function() {
          var mainTerm = $(this).attr("Name");
          var mainTermId = $(this).attr("Id");
          if (mainTerm != undefined) {
            html += "<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + mainTermId + "'>" + mainTerm + "</li>";
            html += "<ul>";
            $(data).find("Sector").each(function() {
              var sector = $(this).attr("Name");
              var sectorId = $(this).attr("Id");
              var sectorParent = $(this).attr("Parent");
              if (sector != undefined && sectorParent == mainTerm) {
                html += "<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + sectorId + "'>" + sector + "</li>";
                html += "<ul>";

                $(data).find("SubSector").each(function() {
                  var subSector = $(this).attr("Name");
                  var subSectorId = $(this).attr("Id");
                  var subSectorParent = $(this).attr("Parent");
                  if (subSector != undefined && subSectorParent == sector) {
                    html += "<li><input type='checkbox' name='mainTerm[]' value='" + subSectorId + "'>" + subSector + "</li>";
                  }
                });
                html += "</ul>";
              }
            });
            html += "</ul>";
          }

          $('[ELEMENT YOU WANT TO UPDATE]').html(html);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Here the function doesn't return anything but instead the success callback takes the responsibility to insert the HTML it generates.  You need to go about it this way because the call to $.ajax() will fire immediately but the call to it's success callback won't fire until after the AJAX URL is returned.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of that?  I am having a hard time finding anything like that.  Only examples of the xml being inline with the javascript.

Comment: I adapted your function, but without the line of code that was calling your `loadSeviceLineXML()` the best I can do is show you where you would inject the HTML.

Comment: Awesome.  I just had to throw a div tag in and update it...   html += "<div id='loadService'>";
 html +=  "<ul>";
 html += "Hello ";
 //Insert test stuff  - Taxonomy
   html +=  loadSeviceLineXML();    Thanks a lot Jason!!!  by the way I would up vote you but I don't have enough reputation points to vote!.